# .htaccess file in codeigniter present a 500 error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just finished my website, using codeigniter, i uploaded the site to a bluehost account as an addon domain

i don't use query_strings, and here is where it in my config file:

```
 $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

the site is going yo work well in my testing server, but upload it to my bluehost account, i face some issue when trying to navigate any page otherwise the homepage

the problem that there is another codeigniter website located in the root of the host and had .htaccess file to let it work correctly, so when creating new site pointing to a folder inside the main domain site, i think that there is issue with the .htaccess of my addon site

here is my .htaccess for the addon site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /http://www.mydomain.com/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: comment out one line at a time and which one is causing the 500 error, that rewrite base looks fishy too, but im 100% sure

Comment: rewrite base `RewriteBase /http://www.domain.com/`????

Comment: @Bookf of Zeus: ya Im thinking that its making the redirect confused, possibly unreachable or internal loop?

Comment: RewriteBase /http://www.sample-domain.com/

Comment: yes, the problem that there is one website included in another one and the two are using .htaccess

Comment: the RewriteBase can be / but just set the DirectoryIndex to where the index of your application is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybod, thanks Eli you solved it, i added the directoryindex and here is the final .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|application/views/|robots\.txt|install|favicon\.ico|documents)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php


#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
     # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Apache [doc on RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase):

> The default setting is: `RewriteBase`*`physical-directory-path`*.
>
> When a substitution occurs for a new URL, this module has to re-inject the URL into the server processing. To be able to do this it needs to know what the corresponding URL-prefix or URL-base is. By default this prefix is the corresponding filepath itself. However, for most websites, URLs are NOT directly related to physical filename paths, so this assumption will often be wrong! Therefore, you can use the RewriteBase directive to specify the correct URL-prefix.

How does bluehost implement add-on domains?  If you can use a control panel to point http://www.mydomain.com/ to **DOCROOT/addon**, then this `.htaccess` file is in `DOCROOT/addon` then in this context it should be:

```
RewriteBase /
```

If it simply points all mapped domains to DOCROOT (as mine does), then you need to use %{HTTP_HOST} decoding and `RewriteCond`s and there are many example in related Qs of how to do this, and this requires extra dispatch line in your DOCROOT .htacces, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        !^/addon/                [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          =www.mydomain.com        [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)                addon/$1                 [L]
```