# CodeIgniter installation questions

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

When I upload the CodeIgniter package to my web server on Bluehost, I can get into the main page, but not sure if this is all I have to do.

I've read many questions here about the same issue, but nothing worked for me. As I understand that I have to add some code [.htaccess codeignitor code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154652/htaccess-file-in-codeigniter-present-a-500-error-page) to the `root .htaccess`, but that made a mess in my url redirection.

I verified that `mod_rewrite` is working fine through some php code, but still unsure about the installation procedure. did any have this framework works on his Bluehost webserver??

I found the installation guide  on [this site](http://www.php-linux.com/home/node/18), but the test fails back to 404 page.

**By the way, I uploaded the package on a subdomain folder**

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nothing wrong with Bluehost.. I've upload my CI into a subdomain folder in Bluehost. and nothing wrong.. It work perfectly..
Some questions :

1. Do you set your base_url correctly? or you can leave it blank.
2. Are you sure you've write the right .htaccess, and put it in the right place? make sure the index page in the config file is blank.

Comment: @Boddy. Thanks for the comments. here is what I did, I created a new folder under my public_html/codeign then uploaded the package there. I changed some stuff at the config.php like base_url to https://www.mydomain.com/codeign   then $config left it the same blank. I tried to add .htacces in the root, but wasn't sure exactly which code and the location. so I made .htaccess after all in the same folder public_html/codeign , but didn't work. I'm sure I'm missing something here, but not sure where... any idea how to do that...

Comment: based on my experience, I add this :
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
in .htaccess and place it on the same directory with application folder (that mean public_html/codeign in your case).

Comment: Thanks. yes, now it works well. That was very useful, but I was wondering why you didn't use **<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>** in your .htaccess?

Comment: because I assume that the rewrite module always enable :p